# Accessing the path in inbound-gateway to set a header

Tags: spring-integration, spring-ws

I have several http gateways that processes different URL paths an eventually route tehm to s service activator using a common router channel. I need to extract the version and service name from the http request, before I send to the router.  Version is easy, I have a corresponding HTTP header for this.  However, the service name has to be extracted from the URL path.

Some examples:

```
/json/ContactService/query = "ContactService"
/json/ContactService/associations/query ="ContactService"
/json/ContactService/1234 = "ContactService"
```

I have a rather brute force method that determines the service from the URL path:

```
String service = null;

URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
String path = url.getPath();

String[] parts = path.split("/");

// iterate over the parts of the url and find the service part
for(String s : parts) {
    if(s.indexOf("Service") > -1) {
        service = s;
    }       
}
```

However I do not like this approach as if the service names ever change, then I need to update the code.  Plus, it doesn't take into account slashes and other nuances with URLs.  Ideally I would like to set the header using SPeL in the gateway, because each gateway handles different paths, I can set the service name accordingly using a segment of the path.

Example (with psuedo code for SPeL):

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway 
        path="/*Service/query, /*Service/count" request-channel="JSONRequestChannel" reply-channel="JSONResponseChannel"
        supported-methods="POST" reply-timeout="5000" request-payload-type="java.lang.String"
        error-channel="CommonErrorChannel" mapped-request-headers="version, HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS">
        <int-http:header name="service" expression="path.parts[path.parts.length-2]" />
</int-http:inbound-gateway>


<int-http:inbound-gateway 
        path="/*Service/association/query" request-channel="JSONRequestChannel" reply-channel="JSONResponseChannel"
        supported-methods="POST" reply-timeout="5000" request-payload-type="java.lang.String"
        error-channel="CommonErrorChannel" mapped-request-headers="version, HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS">
        <int-http:header name="service" expression="path.parts[path.parts.length-3]" />
</int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

One issue i have encountered is a NPE trying to use http_requestUrl header in a SPeL; it does not seem to be set when I try to use it in int-header.

Answer (score 0):

It's a chicken and egg problem - the message doesn't exist yet when those headers are being created, so you can't use `headers['foo']` in these expressions. In fact, those headers (URL etc) are the last thing added before the message is created; there is no `#this` object for these expressions, just the [variables listed here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#uri-template-variables-and-expressions) (`#pathVariables` etc).

In order to make it available here, we would have to add it as a variable to the evaluation context (something like `#uri`). But that would require a framework change.

I think your only option at this point would be to add a `<header-enricher/>` between the gateways and the router (because then the `http_requestUrl` will be available).

EDIT:

Alternatively, you can access the `HttpServletRequest` directly, using this...

```
<int-http:header name="foo" 
expression="T(org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder)
.requestAttributes.request.requestURI"/>
```

(linefeed added for readability)

Comment: Added another alternative.

Comment: Can you please update 'variables listed here' url which currently leads to 404. Thanks